# Can't ping Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, networking, mac, osx-mountain-lion

[image: Network utility snap]

I can't ping my mountain lion from the LAN, but my mac can ping any machine in the LAN.

I was digging into why this could be happening, I found that in network utility, in Netstat, it shows like gateway is localhost and Flags are UHS. This seems wrong. How can I change this to have my MAC address.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: A computer always reaches its own IP addresses through localhost. If it sent a packet to its MAC address, who would send that packet back to it?!

Comment: Looks like Mountain lion issue but only in certain machines.

Comment: You might have *Enable Stealth Mode* ticked in the Firewall Options section of your Security % Privacy settings

Comment: I confirm that I don't have stealth mode enabled in my firewall section.